# Java/android Not Able to print output of string builder

Tags: java, android

I have the following code

```
public static String GetLocalMasterFileStream(String Operation) throws Exception {

String FullPath = "/sdcard/CM3/advices/advice_master.txt";
String line;
String return_value = "";
System.out.println("path is " + FullPath);
    File file = new File(FullPath);
      if (file.canRead() == true) {System.out.println("Determined that file is readable...");}

    //Read text from file
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));


if (Operation.equals("PreCheck")) {
    line = br.readLine();
    text.append(line.toString() + "\r\n");

    return_value = String.valueOf(text);
} else {
          //add some other stuff to do later here
       }

    br.close();
    System.out.println("value being returned is> " + return_value);
    return return_value;

}
```

The line

```
System.out.println("value being returned is> " + return_value);
```

SHOULD print to the log the contents of the first line, which is some letters and a number basically in the txt file. It does not. Infact that entire line starting with "value being returned.." is not printed.

If i change it and make return_value = line or just print the variable "line" directly it prints fine and the contents is correct.

Somehow when i put the variable line (or its string value) into the string builder things stop working.

Answer (score 0):

Unless there is a specific reason for you to use the method     `System.out.println();`, I'd use the android built in function for debugging purposes. In short, I do not know the answer to your question, but I have a suggestion to acquire the same result.
Typing the shortcut 'logd' followed by an 'enter' keypress will give you what you need to log whatever you want. 'logt' followed by the 'enter' is required, this combination will give you good and fast information on what you need to know about your running code.

Comment: This should be a comment and _not_ an answer. To critique or request clarification from a question's author you should leave a comment below their post. You can **always** comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone is wondering in the future...
the \r breaks string builder.

i changed 
 text.append(line.toString() + "\r\n");

to
 text.append(line.toString());
 text.append("\n");

and it worked fine